# How to let gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks export socks5:// all_proxy variable instead of sock://

Tags: linux, proxy, gnome, socks, socks5

I want to set proxy for a Gnome system. When I use these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host 127.0.0.1
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 1080
```

to set a proxy for the system, it turns out the system will set the environmental variables `all_proxy` and `ALL_PROXY` to `socks://127.0.0.1:1080`.

But the problem is, many applications in Linux (pip for example) have a problem of dealing with the `socks://` protocol. It asks you to be specific about the version of socks, which means I'd better set `all_proxy` and `ALL_PROXY` to `socks5://127.0.0.1:1080` instead of the vague `socks://127.0.0.1:1080`.

What I like about `gsettings` is that it can help me turn on and off the proxy based on my needs. Changing environmental variables with `export` will only take effect in the current terminal session. Changing environmental variables with `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` will make it a permanent proxy. That's why the function of `gsettings` seems to be irreplaceable.

Can we improve the function of `gsettings`? If not, what's the best practice to achieve the desired proxy switch?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find, these settings are copied to environment variables [only by GNOME Terminal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/blob/2977cde30cdebbf2edab82196aa97ef9378b515b/src/terminal-util.cc#L674-695) and not for the entire GNOME session, so you can safely adjust them through your terminal shell's startup scripts, e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
if [[ $all_proxy ]]; then
    all_proxy=${all_proxy/#socks:/socks5:}
fi
if [[ $ALL_PROXY ]]; then
    ALL_PROXY=${ALL_PROXY/#socks:/socks5:}
fi
```

Comment: The problem is I need to turn it on and off sometimes based on the needs. Editing `~/.bashrc` seems to be a one-time thing that won't meet my needs. Now that you show the place where the code's at, I'm thinking about editing the source code to replace this intended `gsettings` function.

Comment: Not sure I see the problem. The .bashrc code doesn't interfere with you turning off the proxy settings.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you are right... The proxy's on and off is only controlled by `org.gnome.system.proxy mode`...

Comment: But I still raised an issue to the Gnome GitLab because I think the effort of editing `~/.bashrc` by ourselves should be waived...not to mention if someone needs to change the address of proxy in run time, without rebooting...

Comment: No, you're not right. If you turn off proxy by `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'`, those environmental variables are all gone (unset). Therefore, there is a necessity in using gsettings to switch on and off of the proxy. And editing `~/.bashrc` won't help this case.

Comment: Why not? Your .bashrc won't crash if the variables are unset; and I'm not sure where you got the reboot requirement from? Even if you did put the settings directly in .bashrc that wouldn't require a reboot, but that's not even what I was suggesting at all.

Comment: You are right, setting variables in `.bashrc` will keep the variables alive even when `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'`. But I wonder why. Why `all_proxy` and `ALL_PROXY` disappear if they are set by `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'` then disabled by `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'`. Why won't they disappear if they are set in `.bashrc` then disabled by `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'`.

Comment: That sounds like you've edited .bashrc to set the variables to a fixed value, instead of making it adjust the existing value only? The code in gnome-terminal applies environment variables _before_ starting the shell, while .bashrc does its job _after_ the shell has started – gnome-terminal cannot forcefully unset the environment variables that another process has, much less ones that it will have "in the future".